# Matrix representation of a symmetric positive definite matrix $X$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $X$ is positive semidefinite with eigenvalues $\lambda_i\ge 0$. We can write $X=Q\Lambda Q^T$ for a diagonal matrix $\Lambda$. But why is this equivalent to

$$X=\sum_i \lambda_iq_iq_i^T$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a matter of carrying out the matrix multiplication. If the $q_i$ are the columns of $Q$, then $Q_{ij} = (q_j)_i$, the $i$-th entry of $q_j$. Also $\Lambda_{ij} = \delta_{ij}\lambda_j$. Hence,

$$ X_{ij} = \sum_{k,m} Q_{ik}\lambda_{k}\delta_{km}Q_{jm} = \sum_m \lambda_m (q_m)_i(q_m)_j.$$

The right hand side is also exactly the $ij$-element of $$ \sum_m \lambda_m q_m q_m ^T.$$